# plv8 fetch data from remote website

Tags: postgresql-9.4, functions

I'm trying to retrieve data from openstreetmaps reverse geocoder with plv8. I have tried to look at the documentation but cannot find any info on how to get data from an URL which is returned as JSON to then parse it in the function.

Can anyone assist on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a horrible idea. You're much better off

- doing this in the app (where you can make better use of asyc with v8).
- using [PostGIS tiger geocoder](http://postgis.net/docs/Extras.html)

On the flip side, I don't think you can. PLv8 can load modules if they're in the database. But, I don't think it has network access.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely correct. Went through some docs and examples and came to the sam conclusion. Moved the reverse geocoding in the app.